# Excel VBA reference to ACEDAO.DLL no longer working after MS Office update

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, dao

I've got an VBA module in Excel that uses ACEADO.DLL ("Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library") to dynamically pull and push data from a Microsoft Access database.

I'm aware that this is an fairly obsolete API, but the amount of coding required to replace it with a more modern architecture is prohibitively expensive.

After a recent Office 365 update, my code stopped working. I'm getting this error message : [VBA error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHoJg.png) (it translates in English to "System Error: &H800700C1....").

Note that the VBA debugger does not pop up: the error message appears directly and the code execution stops there.

I was able to replicate the issue on several machines. All had the same Office 365 patch installed. Here are the versions of Excel and Access:

- Excel: Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2212 Build 16.0.15928.20278) 32 bits
- Access: Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2212 Build 16.0.15928.20278) 32 bits

I stepped in the code and found out that it was crashing when trying to open my Access Database with an instruction such as:

```
  Dim engine As DAO.DBEngine
  Dim workspace As DAO.workspace
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim myPath As String
  myPath = "database.accdb"
  Set engine = DAO.DBEngine 'The code crashes here
  Set workspace = engine.CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", DAO.dbUseJet)
  Set db = workspace.OpenDatabase(myPath, , True)
```

Digging a bit deeper, my VBA code references the ACEADO.DLL (on my machine "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\ACEADO.dll"). This is where it gets interesing: there is no such file at this location. I don't know if anything was there before latest Office 365 upgrade, but the code used to run without issues just a week or two ago.

My questions are:

- Has anyone experienced similar issues?
- Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be ACEDAO.DLL, not ACEADO.DLL. And for the record, DAO is not obsolete at all.

Comment: @Andre, correct in title but typo in narrative.

Comment: Issue certainly been around a while https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/acedaodll-is-crashing-after-upgrading-ms-office/9ea9216a-9eb5-4316-b585-71fc9332d90e